# using lag results within the same mutate function dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, data-analysis, rolling-computation, accumulate

I want to replicate the below formula R using `dplyr` + lag function.  The code works till the 2nd row of each group and then onward gives me 0s

forecast = lag(value,1)*(1-lag(Attrition)/52)

Conditions:

1. the first value for forecast should be empty as we already have the Value.
2. second row calculates from the previous values of Attrition and Value columns.
3. third row onward the previous values should be picked from forecast(not Value column) and attrition columns respectively.

I am getting 0's from 3rd row onward. Below is my code for reproducing.

```
data <- data %>% group_by(Patch) %>% mutate(id = row_number())
data <- data %>% group_by(Patch) %>% mutate(forecast = lag(Value,1)*(1-lag(Attrition,1)/52))

tbl_df(data)
# A tibble: 12 x 6
   Patch Week       Value Attrition    id forecast
   <chr> <date>     <dbl>     <dbl> <int>    <dbl>
 1 11P11 2021-06-14     2     0.075     1   NA    
 2 11P11 2021-06-21     0     0.075     2    2.00 
 3 11P11 2021-06-28     0     0.075     3    0    
 4 11P12 2021-06-14     3     0.075     1   NA    
 5 11P12 2021-06-21     0     0.075     2    3.00 
 6 11P12 2021-06-28     0     0.075     3    0    
 7 11P12 2021-07-05     0     0.075     4    0    
 8 11P13 2021-06-14     1     0.075     1   NA    
 9 11P13 2021-06-21     0     0.075     2    0.999
10 11P13 2021-06-28     0     0.075     3    0    
11 11P13 2021-07-05     0     0.075     4    0    
12 11P13 2021-07-12     0     0.075     5    0   


> dput(data)
structure(list(Patch = c("11P11", "11P11", "11P11", "11P12", 
"11P12", "11P12", "11P12", "11P13", "11P13", "11P13", "11P13", 
"11P13"), Week = structure(c(18792, 18799, 18806, 18792, 18799, 
18806, 18813, 18792, 18799, 18806, 18813, 18820), class = "Date"), 
    Value = c(2, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), Attrition = c(0.075, 
    0.075, 0.075, 0.075, 0.075, 0.075, 0.075, 0.075, 0.075, 0.075, 
    0.075, 0.075), id = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
    3L, 4L, 5L), forecast = c(NA, 1.99711538461538, 0, NA, 2.99567307692308, 
    0, 0, NA, 0.998557692307692, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L), groups = structure(list(Patch = c("11P11", "11P12", "11P13"
), .rows = structure(list(1:3, 4:7, 8:12), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Please share your datasets in a copy-pastable format with `dput(YOUR_DATASET)` or smaller samples with `dput(head(YOUR_DATASET))`.

Comment: Added the dput part

Comment: Ankit! Haven't any of the answers served your purpose?

Answer (score 2):

**Updated Solution**

Here is a simple solution using `base::Reduce`:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, df$Patch), function(x) {
  x$forecast <- c(NA, Reduce(function(a, b) {
    a * (1 - (x$Attrition[b]/52))
  }, 2:(nrow(x)-1), init = x$Value[1], accumulate = TRUE))
  x
}))

   Patch       Week Value Attrition id  forecast
1  11P11 2021-06-14     2     0.075  1        NA
2  11P11 2021-06-21     0     0.075  2 2.0000000
3  11P11 2021-06-28     0     0.075  3 1.9971154
4  11P12 2021-06-14     3     0.075  1        NA
5  11P12 2021-06-21     0     0.075  2 3.0000000
6  11P12 2021-06-28     0     0.075  3 2.9956731
7  11P12 2021-07-05     0     0.075  4 2.9913524
8  11P13 2021-06-14     1     0.075  1        NA
9  11P13 2021-06-21     0     0.075  2 1.0000000
10 11P13 2021-06-28     0     0.075  3 0.9985577
11 11P13 2021-07-05     0     0.075  4 0.9971175
12 11P13 2021-07-12     0     0.075  5 0.9956793
```

**Earlier Approach**

You can also use the following approach. For this I first applied your formula with mutate on your data set to get the first value of my `forecast` series. Then I sliced the first rows of each group that contains `NA` values for `forecast` out. After that I used `accumulate` function to calculate your desired series using first `forecast` value as the value for `.init` argument. Then I bind the resulting data set with the one containing `NA` values:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>%
  group_by(Patch) %>%
  mutate(forecast = lag(Value)*(1-(lag(Attrition)/52))) %>%
  filter(between(row_number(), 2, n())) %>%
  mutate(forecast = accumulate(Attrition[-1], .init = forecast[1], ~ ..1 * (1-(..2/52)))) %>%
  bind_rows(df %>% group_by(Patch) %>%
              mutate(forecast = lag(Value)*(1-(lag(Attrition)/52))) %>%
              slice_head()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  arrange(Patch, Week)

# A tibble: 12 x 6
   Patch Week       Value Attrition    id forecast
   <chr> <date>     <dbl>     <dbl> <int>    <dbl>
 1 11P11 2021-06-14     2     0.075     1   NA    
 2 11P11 2021-06-21     0     0.075     2    2.00 
 3 11P11 2021-06-28     0     0.075     3    1.99 
 4 11P12 2021-06-14     3     0.075     1   NA    
 5 11P12 2021-06-21     0     0.075     2    3.00 
 6 11P12 2021-06-28     0     0.075     3    2.99 
 7 11P12 2021-07-05     0     0.075     4    2.99 
 8 11P13 2021-06-14     1     0.075     1   NA    
 9 11P13 2021-06-21     0     0.075     2    0.999
10 11P13 2021-06-28     0     0.075     3    0.997
11 11P13 2021-07-05     0     0.075     4    0.996
12 11P13 2021-07-12     0     0.075     5    0.994
```

Comment: Very cool! I was trying to make `accumulate()` work for this.

Comment: Thank you very much dear @ktiu . I took a glance at your solution and tried to come up with a different approach and came up with this. Although it may sound strange, it works since the `forecast` value for first rows are always `NA`. Your solution is quite subtle and technical. I am also a big fan of your coding style.

Answer (score 2):

If I am understanding you correctly, perhaps you need only `accumulate` from `purrr` (you don't need `lag` values but `accumulated` values instead)-

- I calculated `FORECAST` as per formula given
- Used only `attrition` in argument because we need only first value of `Value` which we can supply to `accumulate` through `.init`
- Now resultant vector will be one length more than desired so stripped its last `-n()` value.
- But your further requirement is to have first result as NA, so stripped the result of one more value i.e. first value by subsetting accumulate as `[-c(1, n()]`
- Now concatenated the results with `NA` in beginning

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% group_by(Patch) %>%
  mutate(FORECAST = c(NA, accumulate(Attrition, .init = first(Value), ~ .x * (1 - .y/52))[-c(1, n())]))

#> # A tibble: 12 x 7
#> # Groups:   Patch [3]
#>    Patch Week       Value Attrition    id forecast FORECAST
#>    <chr> <date>     <dbl>     <dbl> <int>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#>  1 11P11 2021-06-14     2     0.075     1   NA       NA    
#>  2 11P11 2021-06-21     0     0.075     2    2.00     2.00 
#>  3 11P11 2021-06-28     0     0.075     3    0        1.99 
#>  4 11P12 2021-06-14     3     0.075     1   NA       NA    
#>  5 11P12 2021-06-21     0     0.075     2    3.00     3.00 
#>  6 11P12 2021-06-28     0     0.075     3    0        2.99 
#>  7 11P12 2021-07-05     0     0.075     4    0        2.98 
#>  8 11P13 2021-06-14     1     0.075     1   NA       NA    
#>  9 11P13 2021-06-21     0     0.075     2    0.999    0.999
#> 10 11P13 2021-06-28     0     0.075     3    0        0.997
#> 11 11P13 2021-07-05     0     0.075     4    0        0.996
#> 12 11P13 2021-07-12     0     0.075     5    0        0.993
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

What's tricky about this is that you need to consecutively build the `forecast` variable, which is why it won't work in a standard `mutate()` call.

Here is my approach that relies on `purrr`'s `map()` and `reduce()` for data consolidation:

```
library(tidyverse)

data %>%
  mutate(forecast = NA) %>%
  split(~ Patch) %>%
  map(~ .x %>%
          pmap(~ tibble(...)) %>%
          reduce(\(.x, .y) {
            prev <- slice_tail(.x)
            base_value <- ifelse(prev$Value != 0, prev$Value, prev$forecast)
            bind_rows(.x,
                      mutate(.y,
                             forecast = base_value * 1 - prev$Attrition / 5))
          })) %>%
  reduce(bind_rows)
```

Returns:

```
# A tibble: 12 x 6
   Patch Week       Value Attrition    id forecast
   <chr> <date>     <dbl>     <dbl> <int>    <dbl>
 1 11P11 2021-06-14     2     0.075     1   NA
 2 11P11 2021-06-21     0     0.075     2    1.98
 3 11P11 2021-06-28     0     0.075     3    1.97
 4 11P12 2021-06-14     3     0.075     1   NA
 5 11P12 2021-06-21     0     0.075     2    2.98
 6 11P12 2021-06-28     0     0.075     3    2.97
 7 11P12 2021-07-05     0     0.075     4    2.95
 8 11P13 2021-06-14     1     0.075     1   NA
 9 11P13 2021-06-21     0     0.075     2    0.985
10 11P13 2021-06-28     0     0.075     3    0.97
11 11P13 2021-07-05     0     0.075     4    0.955
12 11P13 2021-07-12     0     0.075     5    0.94
```

Data used:

```
data <- structure(list(Patch = c("11P11", "11P11", "11P11", "11P12", "11P12", "11P12", "11P12", "11P13", "11P13", "11P13", "11P13", "11P13"), Week = structure(c(18792, 18799, 18806, 18792, 18799, 18806, 18813, 18792, 18799, 18806, 18813, 18820), class = "Date"), Value = c(2, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), Attrition = c(0.075, 0.075, 0.075, 0.075, 0.075, 0.075, 0.075, 0.075, 0.075, 0.075, 0.075, 0.075), id = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), forecast = c(NA, 1.99711538461538, 0, NA, 2.99567307692308, 0, 0, NA, 0.998557692307692, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -12L), groups = structure(list(Patch = c("11P11", "11P12", "11P13"), .rows = structure(list(1:3, 4:7, 8:12), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```